# Mostrar informacion dependiendo de lo que el usuario elija

Tags: php, sql

Tengo una base de datos con varias tablas relacionadas, una tabla de productos relacionada con una de categorías, lo que quiero es mostrar a través de un `<select>` todas las categorías(eso si lo puedo hacer) pero que al seleccionar una me de todos los productos que pertenecen a esa categoría!.

Así muestro las categorías

```
<?php 
  $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'bd_productos3' );
  if($db->connect_errno){
    die('Error');
  }
  $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM clasificacion");
  $htmlPJ = '<form action="" method="post">';
  $htmlPJ .= 'Clasificacion <select id="select">';
  $sql = "select * from clasificacion";
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $htmlPJ.= "<option  value='{$row['id_clasificacion']}' > {$row['nombre_clasificacion']} </option>";
  }
  $htmlPJ .= '</select>';
  $htmlPJ .= '<input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="enviar">';
  $htmlPJ .= '</form>';
  echo $htmlPJ;
?>
```

necesito que al seleccionar una categoría me muestre los productos que están relacionados con esa categoría.

Les agradezco sus comentarios

Comment: Deberás hacer otra consulta con un filtro que recogerás en la parte cliente, dónde lo usarás para formar la sql query

Comment: Deberías usar ajax.

Comment: estoy null en ajax y jquery :(

Comment: Una alternativa a ajax es enviar parametros por GET y recargar esa pagina con la información que envias por la url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberias trabajar con javascript, echarle un vistazo a jQuery o algun framework JS, claro esta que antes familiarizarte con estos conceptos de ajax y otros relacionados a este tipo de actividades. Te comparto un mini script de como se trabajaría esto con jQuery.

```
$('#category_select').on('change', function(e) {
  var categorySelected = this.value;
  $.ajax(function() {
    method: 'post',
    data: {categoria: categorySelected},
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'archivodeproductos.php',
    success: function(productos) {
      $.each(productos, function(index, element) {
        // Aca imprimirias tus productos a como los muestres creando el html con jQuery..
      })
    }

  })

});
```

Y pues en php recibirias el valor enviado en *archivodeproductos.php* para hacer la peticion a la base de datos y devolver los valores de productos que encontro, para asi mostrarlos a traves de jquery.

```
$categoriaSeleccionada = $_POST['categoria'];
// Aqui haces tu consulta a la base datos con la categoria seleccionada..
// Al final guardas en un arreglo tus productos y los envias de regreso..
// Para imprimirlo con jQuery
echo json_encode($productos)
```

Espero te sea útil y puedas completar esto.
Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo hago de la siguiente manera.

**Mi HTML**

```
<div id="estadoList"></div><br>
<div id="municipioList"></div><br>
<div id="parroquiaList"></div><br>
```

**Mi JS**

```
function getEstado(){

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlhttp3 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp3.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp3.readyState==4 && xmlhttp3.status==200){
            document.getElementById("estadoList").innerHTML=xmlhttp3.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp3.open("GET","includes/getEstado.php",true);
    xmlhttp3.send();
}
//****************************************************************
function getMunicipio(ciudad_id){

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlhttp3 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp3.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp3.readyState==4 && xmlhttp3.status==200){
            document.getElementById("municipioList").innerHTML=xmlhttp3.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp3.open("GET","includes/getMunicipio.php?idestado="+ciudad_id,true);
    xmlhttp3.send();
}

//****************************************************************
function getParroquia(muncipio_id){

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlhttp3 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp3.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp3.readyState==4 && xmlhttp3.status==200){
            document.getElementById("parroquiaList").innerHTML=xmlhttp3.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp3.open("GET","includes/getParroquia.php? idmunicipio="+muncipio_id,true);
    xmlhttp3.send();
}
```

Este codigo lo que hace es buscarte un estado de tu base de datos, de ahi seleccionas uno y te aparece otro select con los municipios de ese estado y luego igual que arriba pero aparecen las parroquias.

Yo uso esa función amigo, solo cámbiala a tu gusto y ya. Espero la puedas entender, aunque con **PHP** sabrás como se usa el method GET así que esos cambios no te serán dificiles.

Espero poderte ayudar y no recuerdo el nombre de donde saque el codigo para darle el crédito :)